# Adobe file prints incorrectly

Tags: windows, printing, acrobat, adobe-reader

I have a pdf file as attached below:

[required print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KotD2.png)

When I print it, the square text box are not printed. It prints as this one:

[incorrect print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc8hC.png)

It is necessary to print the square grids as well. Any ideas please..

I am using adobe reader latest version and acrobat dc pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viele Viele Bunte Böxlis…

What you see in "required print" is provided by the PDF viewer (in other words Acrobat/Reader), and not part of the field properties. Acrobat/Reader has an option to show fillable fields with a particular color, and to display fields set as "required" with a specific colored border. In the example, the fillable field color is the default pale blue, and the border color the default red.

In the "incorrect print" picture, you see how the blank form prints; fill in some data, and it should a bit clearer on how it looks like.

In Reader, you can't do anything about the situation.

In Acrobat, you can get at the field properties, and set a border width and color. You may also check whether the fields are really set to be visible.

HOWEVER, having single character text fields for entering data is not very smart, and is considered as a beginner's fault. And making all those boxes required is even worse (because the required property only kicks in when submitting data to a server, and in that case, single character fields are useless…). Instead, make regular text fields, and then set the Comb property with the according number of characters for the field.